# Communication between shared (Activity/NavGraph-scoped) ViewModel and Fragment ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

Android with NavigationComponents and communication between shared (Activity/NavGraph-scoped)  ViewModel and Fragment ViewModel.

How would you achieve it?

1. Both injected into Fragment and Fragment works as a proxy
2. SharedViewModel injected into FragmentViewModel

EDIT:
Same communication as here but DetailFragment has own ViewModel

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: On a high level, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to achieve state sharing between fragments? Like lets say, your activity has a host fragment and host fragment has other child fragments and you want to share the same viewmodel between parent and child fragments? Which DI framework are you using ?

Comment: Same communication as here but DetailFragment has own ViewModel

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: I do not think that should be much hassle then. The host activity will have a viewmodel which you will share with the list fragment, upon a list item click, you will have to pass the data that you want in the Detail Fragment using something like this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data . The detail fragment can then be injected with its own viewmodel.

Comment: This use case was very simplified. Just accept that I need SharedViewModel and DetailedFragmentViewModel inside DetailedFragment and I need communication between them.

Comment: I do not see why you would need a separate viewmodel for detail of the list item then. I think you could do with a single viewmodel. The viewmodel will be a lil bloated but way simpler, but its a wild wild world, maybe your usecase does need different viewmodel. I hope you find the solution to this. Good luck